# URL Schemes for most popular mobile platforms

Tags: android, ios, url, url-scheme

We simply want to open the Google Map app (on the most popular smartphone operating systems) to a specific lat/long, and show traffic.

This works on the iPhone, comgooglemaps://?center=39.718042,-104.959302&zoom=14&views=traffic

What is the equivalent for Android?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you can fire an Intent this way:

```
String lat = "48.856035";
String lng = "2.346030";
startActivity(this, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:" + lat + "," + lng));
```

All other parameters can be found at [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps)